# Unnest pandas column of lists to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have column of lists looks like that -
df['movie-data'][0] (30K rows)

```
[{'genre': 'movie genre',
  'movie': 'movie title',
  'actor-name': 'name',
  'co-stars': [['name', 'name', 'name']]}]
```

I would like to take this column and split it to 4 different columns.
I tried this solution -

```
split_df = pd.DataFrame(list(df['movie-data']), columns=['genre', 'movie', 'actor-name','costars'])
```

failed because nan valus -

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

There is better solution or how to handle the nan values?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
lst = [{'genre': 'movie genre',
  'movie': 'movie title',
  'actor-name': 'name',
  'co-stars': [['name', 'name', 'name']]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst).explode('co-stars').explode('co-stars')
```

Or, if you always have a [[]] format:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(lst)
      .assign(**{'co-stars': lambda d: d['co-stars'].str[0]})
      .explode('co-stars')
     )
```

output:

```
         genre        movie actor-name co-stars
0  movie genre  movie title       name     name
0  movie genre  movie title       name     name
0  movie genre  movie title       name     name
```

Comment: Yap its looks good but not solving the nan (float) problem

Comment: @Ofek can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Each row in df['movie-data'] columns is list like i showed above -
df['movie-data'][ i ] = [{'genre': 'movie genre',
  'movie': 'movie title',
  'actor-name': 'name',
  'co-stars': [['name', 'name', 'name']]}]

And there is 'nan' values in there  - those pop the error i mentioned above.